# Bubble Sort using Assembly x86-64 for Linux and display on screen the sorted vector

Tags: assembly, nasm

I created this code to sort an array with *n* positions using NASM x86-64 on Linux but I can't see the value ​​in each iteraction, apparently I can't access them. Also, I created a loop to display each element of the vector on the screen but it doesn't. Can someone help me?

```
section .data
    global vec
    vec db 53, 
        db 51,
        db 57
    cont equ $-vec
    var1 db 0
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    
    mov r8d, cont
    dec r8d
    
    laco:
        mov ebx, r8d
        mov ecx, vec

        comp_comutar:
            mov eax, [ecx]
            mov edx, [ecx+1]
            cmp eax, edx
            jl n_comutar
            mov [ecx], edx
            mov [ecx+1], eax

        n_comutar:
            inc ecx
            dec ebx
            jnz comp_comutar
    dec r8d
    jnz laco
    
    mov ebx, cont
    mov ecx, vec
    
    loop_print:
        mov [var1], ecx
        inc ecx
        mov eax, 1
        mov edi, 1
        mov esi, var1
        mov edx, 1
        dec ebx
        jnz loop_print

    mov eax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall
```

Comment: What does it mean that "*I can't see the value ​​in each iteraction*"?

Answer (score 1):

#### Sizes matter

> ```
> vec db 53, 
>     db 51,
>     db 57
> ```

You have defined the *vec* array containing **bytes**, but your code is processing **dwords**. What happens with these trailing commas? Are you getting an array with 5 elements (53,0,51,0,57) ?

Change

```
mov eax, [ecx]
mov edx, [ecx+1]
cmp eax, edx
jl n_comutar
mov [ecx], edx
mov [ecx+1], eax
```

into

```
movzx eax, byte [rcx]         ;;; mov al, [rcx]
movzx edx, byte [rcx+1]       ;;; mov dl, [rcx+1]
cmp eax, edx                  ;;; cmp al, dl
jl n_comutar
mov [rcx], dl
mov [rcx+1], al
```

> ```
> mov [var1], ecx
> ```

The `ecx` **dword** register holds an address that you store in a **byte**-sized variable!

---

> Also, I created a loop to display each element of the vector on the screen but it doesn't

The display loop sets up for an API call, but you didn't actually include a `syscall` instruction. Also, `RCX` is not call preserved! You can't use it to control your loop.

```
    mov ebx, vec
loop_print:
    mov eax, 1
    mov edi, 1
    mov esi, ebx
    mov edx, 1
    syscall
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx, vec + cont
    jb  loop_print
```

Comment: Trailing commas in NASM don't assemble to any bytes.  e.g. that snippet in the first code-block of your answer assembles to a 3-byte file, just like `db 53, 51, 57` would.  That's consistent with `db '', 0xa` in another recent question assembling to only 1 byte, with the empty string not taking any space.